# Convert Float32Array to Buffer

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to return a binary array of floating points. 
I get a Float32Array from a geotiff library, however the http can only
return a string or buffer so I have to 'convert' it to a buffer.

```
const tiff  = await geotiff.fromUrl(ahnUrl);
const image = await tiff.getImage();
const data  = await image.readRasters(); <-- Is Float32Array
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'});
var buf = Buffer.allocUnsafe( data.width * data.height );
for ( var y = 0; y < data.height; y++ )
{
  for ( var x = 0; x < data.width; x++ )
  {
    buf.writeFloatLE(data[y*data.width+x]);
  }
}
// buf = Buffer.from(data); <-- does not work
// buf = Buffer.from(data.buffer); neither
res.end(buf);
```

The problem is the double for loop, I do not want this.
Ideally, there is no additional data copy and definitely not this
very slow double for loop. Speed is pretty critical.

I am new to javascript/nodejs, but it appears that the Float32Array is multidimensional as
its length returns 1, but its width and height are 1024x1024 (as expected).

The result of 'const buf = Buffer.from(data)' is a buffer with a single byte length.

Answer (score 1):

I think you've misunderstood the return type of `readRasters`.  As far as I can tell from the [docs](https://github.com/geotiffjs/geotiff.js/blob/master/README.md), it's not by default a `Float32Array`, but an array of arrays (one for each channel, e.g. R, G, and B).

> By default, the raster is split to a separate array for each component. For an RGB image for example, we'd get three arrays, one for red, green and blue.

Try passing `{interleave: true}` to `readRasters`.

> If we want instead all the bands interleaved in one big array, we have to pass the interleave: true option:

After that `Buffer.from` aught to do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

A thanks, this does help.
However, doing Buffer.from( Float32Array ) results in a 1byte per float buffer plus it copies the data.
To get it working you also have to use this package:

```
let toBuffer = require("typedarray-to-buffer")
function()
{
  const data  = await image.readRasters({interleave:true});
  const buf   = toBuffer(data); <-- Now if contains 1 float, this is 4 bytes long.
}
```

Comment: If my answer helped, please consider up-voting or marking it as correct.  Anyway, look at the code for "typedarray-to-buffer".  For TypedArrays like `Float32Array`, all it does is call `Buffer.from(arr.buffer);`  As such I still stand by my answer: it answers the question succinctly without a third-party library.  In other words, providing `interleave: true` and then using `Buffer.from` works correctly.  https://github.com/feross/typedarray-to-buffer/blob/master/index.js#L16